# Use PouchDB as embedded database within phonegap app

Tags: html, cordova, pouchdb

I'm just getting started with PouchDB.  I would like to be able to use PouchDB within HTML5 apps for mobile devices created using Phonegap or Cordova.  While going through the Getting Started guide on the PouchDB site, it looks like you are supposed to run through a server (or localhost) rather than through the file system.  As I am trying to create an app which runs offline,  wouldn't a Phonegap app, in essence, be using the file system on the mobile device and not a server/localhost?

I'm sure this is a basic question, so forgive me if this is too obvious, but I haven't found anything clear on this topic through my searches.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PouchDB is able to sync with a remote database running on a server, such as CouchDB, Cloudant, or Couchbase.

However, it's also perfectly OK to run it as a purely local database. When you do:

```
var db = new PouchDB('foobar');
```

...then you have a local database called "foobar," using either IndexedDB, WebSQL, LevelDB, SQLite, or whatever the browser/device supports. So ultimately it writes to the local filesystem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Good to have the confirmation.  When I watched your video you said that it was 'bad juju' to use PouchDB from the file system so we should run the local server.  It does work, however, just as you have described.  This is a great project (ie. PouchDB).

Comment: I don't think that's what I was referring to when I said "bad juju" (although I don't recall). :) Ultimately IndexedDB, WebSQL, LevelDB, and SQLite _all_ represent the local filesystem, and if you prefer that to a remote server, you'll have better performance (because no network requests) and it will work offline.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/)!

I reckon this may be a good example for you build a offline apps. In fact, you could use Angular + pouchDB + websql. I am working on some projects which related to that. Look forward to further questions.